# ASP.NET: HttpUtility.UrlEncode stop adding our site prefix?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Is there a way to stop HttpUtility.URLEncode from always prefixing any raw URL we give it with our own site's URL? (e.g. http://localhost:45852/LocalSite/pages/display)

For example:

```
 Dim strReturn As String = ""

 strReturn += "http://maps.apple.com/?q="
 strReturn += vClsVendor.pAddressLine1.Trim
 strReturn += "+"
 strReturn += vClsVendor.pAddressLine2.Trim

 strReturn = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strReturn)
```

Gives the following result:

```
http://localhost:453432/LocalSite1/pages/display/http%3a%2f%2fmaps.apple.com%2f%3fq%3d1+McDonald%2527s+Way%2bRonaldville
```

instead of:

```
http%3a%2f%2fmaps.apple.com%2f%3fq%3d1+McDonald%2527s+Way%2bRonaldville
```

TIA
Mark

2) Reply to Scotty:

Thanks Scotty. I put a breakpoint in and tested it. It was still OK after UrlEncode. It turns out ASP.NET was prefixing at the   <%=strClsGridHTML%> point where strClsGridHTML contained among other things the following href content:

```
href='http%3a%2f%2fmaps.apple.com%2f%3fq%3d123+Water+Way%2bAtlantic%2bDenpasar%2bBali%2b123432%2bIndonesia     '>   




 <div id="dvGrid01">
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFieldSearch" runat="server" Value="0" />
            <%=strClsGridHTML%>

             <div style="clear:both;"></div>

        </div>
```

So maybe ASP.NET looks at http%3a%2f%2fmaps.apple.com%2f%3fq%3d123+Water+Way%2bAtlantic%2bDenpasar%2bBali%2b123432%2bIndonesia and decides it's not an already valid URL and so decides to prefix it with the localhost bit?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour using your code. Are you sure strReturn includes your localhost url if you put a breakpoint after line strReturn = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strReturn)?

Comment: I've never seen UrlEncode do that.